# How to access nid in views

Tags: 7, views, nodes, hooks

I'm trying to build a simple module that renders facebook like boxes for each article. To do that, I need to know full absolute path to article.

I have my views set up to show all published posts as content (teaser). But I would like to insert a custom markup after each item. For that I need to know nid, so I can build a link that leads to article. How can I do that?

Here is how my views is set up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/soP2R.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the rendered entity style I don't think you can do it through the UI - Views passes off the display to `node_view()` in that case, and doesn't get involved with the markup for the row.

The easiest way to do what you want is to implement `hook_preprocess_node()`, look for a View in the current context, and if the node is being rendered as part of that display, you can make some alterations.

For example

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if (!empty($vars['view']) && $vars['view']->view_name == 'foo') {
    $nid = $vars['node']->nid;
    $vars['extra_link'] = l('Some text', "node/$nid");
  }
}
```

Then in your node.tpl.php file you'll have access to `$extra_link`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible for getting the node ids for each item from UI:

- Change the **Format** of view to show **fields** instead of the **content**
- Add the required **fields**, for example: `nid`, `title`, `body` (for body content, you can specify the maximum length of this field, to show it as a teaser), and other needed fields.
- Rewrite the output of any of the added fields (may be `nid`) to have it as markup.

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify how to rewrite the output of views ui? I tried doing exactly what you suggested in here, but couldn't get views hooks to work inside mymodule.module, does views require a .inc file for its hooks to work?

Comment: @WraithLux Actually you can have the template file for you view https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/group/views_templates/7 .

I am not getting what exactly you want to do it on module file. 

You can rewrite the output of any field by clicking on that link and http://awesomescreenshot.com/0c31saw12b